# absorbing balanced sets need not contain open balls

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

We want to show that absorbing sets, balanced sets need not contain (open) balls.

Let $\ X= c_c(\mathbb{N}),  $ equipped with $\|x\|_2$
We know that X is normed space which is not complete.

Let U = {$\ x\ \epsilon \ c_c(\mathbb{N}): \|x\|_1< 1  $}
Then U  is an absorbing and balanced set ( containing 0), but U contains no $\|\ .  \|_2 $ - ball centered at 0.

**Why** does U contains no $\|\ .  \|_2 $ - ball centered at 0?
I don't really see it. Can someone help me , please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because for all $\delta$ you can find $x$ such that $||x||_2<\delta$ and $||x||_1>1$.

Choose $m,N$ such that $\sum_{n\geq m}\frac{1}{n^2}<\delta^2$ and $\sum_{n= m}^N\frac{1}{n}>1$, and define $x=(x_i)_{i\geq 1}$ such that $x_i=\frac{1}{i}$ for $m\leq i\leq N$ and zero otherwise. Then $x$ has the desired property. $\blacksquare$